# Matching each term in a text file against all text files in a directory

Tags: search, awk

I have an awk-generated list of terms, terms.txt. I need to search a directory full of 1000's of small xml files for exact matches to any of the terms in terms.txt.  I need generate a second list, matches.txt, that contains the filename and term for each match.

Can awk be used to do this?  I was thinking that if I use awk to re-format the list like this:
   "term1|term2|term3|..."
...perhaps I could use a variable (VariableName) to represent the reformatted list-string, and then match the terms using this:

```
awk "/VariableName/{ print FILENAME \": \" $0;}" C:\directory\*.txt > matches.txt
```

Is it possible to create and use a variable like this in awk?  If not, is there a better way in awk? Maybe the list can be fed in and matched against the directory one term at a time?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How does your `terms.txt` and `xml` file look like? Can you post a small sample?

Answer (score 2):

Code for GNU [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk -f prog.awk terms.txt "C:\directory\*.txt"
```

```
NR==FNR {t[$0]; next}
{
    for (x in t) {
        p="\\<"x"\\>"
        if (match ($0, p ))
            {
            f[FILENAME]
            m[FILENAME,x]++
            }
        }
}

END {
    for (a in f)
        {
        printf("\n%s", a)
        for (b in t)
            {
            if (m[a,b]) {printf("|%s", b)}
            }
        }
}
```

Matching with `word boundaries`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), but there is simple [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) solution:

```sh
grep -f terms.txt directory/*xml -o
```